# How does Excel trace dependent cells?

Tags: excel

MS Excel can quickly trace all *precedent* cells (ones that are used) and *dependent* cells (ones that use) of a selected cell. I assume that's the fundamental feature for fast recalculation of complex spreadsheets.

While *precedent* cells are explicitly mentioned in current cell's formula (and thus can be found through formula parsing) the *dependent* ones should be stored somewhere else (e.g. as a Cell object property). How does Excel store and update this information?

Comment: Probably it maintains this information whenever you edit a cell. It parses the formula and stores all dependencies that are found in a map/hashtable or in the dependent cell objects.

Answer (score 0):

The calculation of worksheets in Excel can be viewed as a three-stage process:

1. Construction of a dependency tree
2. Construction of a calculation chain
3. Recalculation of cells

The above copied from [Excel Recalculation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687891.aspx) which provides a LOT more explanation though perhaps still not the level of detail sought by the OP. However at some point the level may be considered proprietary and not public knowledge.